# How to activate the typing cursor on a field using selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am having a test case that one of its steps is to activate the typing cursor on a text field then write on that field.

I use "type" command to type but I can't figure out how to activate the typing cursor on that field.

Please help me, it is very important.

Comment: Did you try recording your actions and looking at what code it generates?

Comment: this test logic makes no sense.. why would you **NEED** that cursor to appear?  If your acceptance criteria is written like `"make sure the cursor appears"` then whoever wrote it really needs to think about priorities.  that would be a unit test for the browser, not for you.  `type` is exactly what you want.  As a tester, it's also your responsibility to translate business logic to test logic.  you shouldn't take it all literally most times.

Answer (score 1):

I had an encounter with similar need. In my case after typing in the field, field mask supposed to be applied, but it doesn't react on selenium `type`. `focus` and `sendKeys` helped me here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us the code from selenium ide you're using? Is the field you want to type in an angular field? Is the field "there" before you run the type command?  You might try a "waitforelementpresent" command on the field id first.

Also, if the field is an angular field, I've found that when testing angular, I have to use sendkeys instead of type.

Klendathu